# Exact solution to Dirac delta perturbation for particle in a box

Tags: sequences-and-series, physics, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory, causal-diagrams

Using diagrammatic perturbation theory the energy of a particle in a box with a Dirac delta potential can be closely approximated. The following energy correction terms to the ground state energy ($\mathscr{E}_1$) up to 5th order are found. The question is if anybody recognizes some series or easy way to extend to higher orders.

\begin{align*}
    E^{(0)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{H}_0|1\rangle &= \frac{\pi^2}{2}& \\
    E^{(1)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{V}|1\rangle &= 2&\\
    E^{(2)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{V}|\Psi_1^{(1)}\rangle &= -\frac{2}{\pi^2}& \\
    E^{(3)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{V}|\Psi_1^{(2)}\rangle &= -\frac{2}{3\pi^2} + \frac{8}{\pi^4} \\
    E^{(4)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{V}|\Psi_1^{(3)}\rangle &= \frac{4}{\pi^4} - \frac{40}{\pi^6} \\
    E^{(5)}_1 = \langle 1|\mathscr{V}|\Psi_1^{(4)}\rangle &= \frac{2}{5\pi^4} - \frac{80}{3\pi^6}+ \frac{224}{\pi^8}\\
\end{align*}

$$\mathscr{E}_1=E^{(0)}_1 + E^{(1)}_1 + E^{(2)}_1 + E^{(3)}_1 + E^{(4)}_1 + E^{(5)}_1 + ...$$

I also found a source stating $E^{(5)}_1 = \frac{8}{45\pi^4}-\frac{22}{\pi^6}+\frac{200}{\pi^8}$, the difference is probably caused by human error, I am not sure who is wrong though. (I got it from a Master's student report, which I am not sure if they want to share it publically)

---

### System description

For a particle in an infinite square well ("particle in a box"), the solutions to the one-dimensional Schrödinger equation are known. In a box with length $a$ (for simplicity $a=1$), the particle has a wavefunction/eigenfunction $\psi_n$ with corresponding energy/eigenvalue $E_n$, where $n$ refers to the state, with $n=1$ being the ground state.

$$
\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle\\
\psi_n = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)\\
E_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2}{2a}
$$

A perturbation can be made, specifically a Dirac potential in the middle of the well. This means that the energies and wavefunctions are no longer known. Perturbation theory can approximate the perturbed system using solutions of the unperturbed system.

Look at [Physics Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465459/), which discusses the same problem. However, they did not state any closed form of the different correction terms.

---

### Perturbation theory

The repulsive Dirac potential will change the Schrödinger Equation.
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\delta\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle.
$$
[Perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)), says that the Hamiltonian $\mathscr{H}$ can be split in the unperturbed Hamiltonian $\mathscr{H}_0$ and the perturbation $\mathscr{V}$. Some shorthand notation can be set up.
$$
V_{ij} = \langle i|\mathscr{V}|j\rangle = \langle i|\delta\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)|j\rangle = 2\sin\left(\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{j\pi}{2}\right)\\
E_i^{(0)} = E_i = \frac{i^2\pi^2}{2}.
$$
This shows that $V_{ij}=V_{ji}$ and note that $a=1$ was used.

Using the unperturbed wavefunctions and energies, the ground state energy of the perturbed system ($\mathscr{E}_1$) can be approximated. For the first few terms a closed form can be found, could this be extended to arbitrary order?
$$\mathscr{E}_1=E^{(0)}_1 + E^{(1)}_1 + E^{(2)}_1 + E^{(3)}_1 + E^{(4)}_1 + E^{(5)}_1 + ...$$

---

### Diagrammatic perturbation theory

One way of finding the energy corrections is called **diagrammatic perturbation theory**. "Modern Quantum Chemistry" by Szabo and Ostlund has a chapter on this [1]. It comes down to the fact that diagrams can represent parts of the energy correction terms.

The rules for drawing the diagrams are as follows:

1. Draw $n$ dots vertically, in order.
2. Connect all $n$ dots together with a continuous line, so that each dot has one line passing through it.
3. Do this in all possible distinct ways. diagrams are equivalent if each and every dot is connected to an identical pair of dots.

Then arrows can be added to the lines, lines going down are "hole lines" and lines going up are called "particle lines". The perturbation ($\mathscr{V}$) is represented by the dots.

The rules to translate the diagrams into expressions are as follows:

1. Each dot contributes a factor $\langle\psi_{\text{label line in}}|\mathscr{V}|\psi_{\text{label line out}}\rangle$, to the numerator.
2. Each pair of adjacent dots contributes to the denominator factor $\sum E^{(0)}_{\text{hole}}-E^{(0)}_{\text{particle}}$, this sum runs over all lines crossing a (imaginary) horizontal line separating two adjacent dots
3. The overall sign of the expression is $(-)^{h+l}$, $h$ is the number of hole lines and $l$ is the number of closed loops (which is 1 in this system).

Below the diagrams representing the first four corrections to the energy are shown. Below that their corresponding expressions are given.

[image: diagrammatic perturbation theory 4th order]

\begin{align}
    E^{(1)}_1 = V_{11}&\\
    E^{(2)}_1 = \sum_{n\neq1}& \frac{V_{1n}^2}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)}\\
    E^{(3)}_1 = \sum_{nm\neq1}& \frac{V_{1n}V_{nm}V_{m1}}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)\left(E_1-E_m\right)}-V_{11}\frac{V_{1n}^2}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)^2}\\
    E^{(4)}_1 = \sum_{nmk\neq1}& \frac{V_{1n}V_{nm}V_{mk}V_{k1}}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)\left(E_1-E_m\right)\left(E_1-E_k\right)} + V_{11}^2\frac{V_{1n}^2}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)^3} \\&- V_{11}\frac{V_{1n}V_{nm}V_{m1}}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)^2\left(E_1-E_m\right)}- V_{11}\frac{V_{1n}V_{nm}V_{m1}}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)\left(E_1-E_m\right)^2} \\&- \frac{V_{1n}^2V_{1m}^2}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)\left(2E_1-E_n-E_n\right)\left(E_1-E_m\right)} - \frac{V_{1n}^2V_{1m}^2}{\left(E_1-E_n\right)^2\left(2E_1-E_n-E_n\right)}
\end{align}

One can see that there would be 24 distinct diagrams for the 5th order and 120 for the 6th order. Using Mathematica the infinite sums are then evaluated, and the energies at the top of this post are found.

---

Concluding, is there a series or an easy way to go to higher orders? Possibly is there even an exact solution when going to infinite order?

---

**References:**

[1]: Szabo, A., & Ostlund, N. S. (1996). Modern Quantum Chemistry: Introduction to Advanced Electronic Structure Theory. Courier Corporation.

Comment: To apply a perturbation theory you should have a small parameter (for example, the perturbation potential should look like $\alpha\delta(x-\frac12),\,\alpha\ll1$). Without this condition you cannot get, speaking generally, the asymptotic series.

Comment: This Dirac potential is already (relatively speaking) small. The energy for this system with a 'normal' Dirac potential (so without the $\alpha$) appears to be converging for the first 5 orders. The corrections are progressively getting smaller.  So introducing this $\alpha$ should not be strictly necessary.

Regardless, it would be interesting to see if this $\alpha$ would make a difference, the expressions for the corrections would not change only the definition of $V_{ij}$. So, an answer involving the use of this $\alpha$ would be interesting to see.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this specific case the energy series seems to converge quickly even at $\alpha=1$. I may also suppose that at $\alpha \sim\frac{\pi^2}4\approx 2.5$ the perturbation theory is not applicable. Your question is really interesting, but I'm afraid only few equations in QM have closed solutions...

Comment: You can find an exact solution to this problem in  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465178/if-one-puts-a-delta-function-spike-inside-an-infinite-square-well-is-the-result.

Comment: One other point to note is that those eigenstates which are odd under parity ($x\to \pi-x$) vanish at $x=L/2$ and so are unaffected by the Dirac perturbation at this point. So for the purposes of perturbation theory, it suffices to focus on those solutions which are even under parity (including the ground state).

Comment: Also: the formula for $E_{1}^{(3)}$ seems wrong. The first term is correct, but the second should be $$V_{11}\sum_{n\neq 1}\frac{V_{1n}^2}{(E_1-E_n)^2}$$ (see Eq. (6.14) of Szabo and Ostlund.)  I'm similarly suspicious of the formula for $E_{1}^{(4)}$, in particular the terms which don't depend on $m$ or $k$, but I don't have a reference at hand for it.

Comment: @Semiclassical you are correct, the numerator should be $V_{1n}$, I fixed this mistake. I am pretty confident in the $E_1^{(4)}$ term. Every term should namely have four potential ($V$)  terms and 3 total energy terms ($(E_1-E_i)$ or $(2E_1-E_i-E_j)$). If an index $n$, $m$, or $k$ is used then it should appear twice in the potential terms. And of course, the reference is given in the diagrams provided, if you ever want to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. OP considers the [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) for an [infinite square potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) with a midpoint [Dirac delta potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential)
   $$\begin{align}\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V_0\delta\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)\right)\psi(x) ~=~& E\psi(x),\tag{1a}\cr  
   0~\leq~x~~\leq~L~\equiv~&a,\tag{1b}\cr 
   \psi(0)~=~0~=~&\psi(L), \tag{1c}\cr 
   E~\equiv~&\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}, \qquad k~\geq~0, \tag{1d} \end{align}$$
   OP is seeking to determine the ground state energy $E_1$ as a (not necessarily convergent) [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) of the coupling constant $V_0$ using [Rayleigh-Schrödinger (RS) perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics))$^1$.
2. Instead of RS perturbation theory, it is easier to directly consider the transcendental equation for the odd state eigenvalue of the wave number $k$
   $$ \cot\frac{kL}{2}~=~-\frac{\kappa}{2k}, \qquad \kappa~\equiv~\frac{2m V_0}{\hbar^2}, \tag{2}$$
   derived in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465178/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. Define a dimensionless coupling constant
   $$g~\equiv~\frac{m L}{\hbar^2} \frac{V_0}{\pi}\tag{3} $$
   Then eq. (2) becomes
   $$-\frac{kL}{2}\cot\frac{kL}{2}~=~\frac{\kappa L}{4}~\equiv~ \frac{\pi}{2}g. \tag{4} $$
4. Next replace the wave number $k$ with a dimensionless phase $\phi$:
   $$ \frac{kL}{2} ~\equiv~(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} +\phi \tag{5}$$
   for the $(2n\!+\!1)$th state. We can now rewrite eq. (4) as a fixed-point equation
   $$ \phi~=~\arctan\frac{g}{2n+1+\frac{2}{\pi}\phi}. \tag{6} $$
5. Let us from now on focus on the ground state.
   Eq. (6) with $n=0$ can be solved recursively in the coupling constant $g$
   $$\begin{align} \phi_N~=~&\arctan\frac{g}{1+\frac{2}{\pi}\phi_{N-1}},\qquad N~\in\mathbb{N},\cr
   \phi_0~=~&0. \end{align}\tag{7} $$
   The $N$th iteration is exact to $N$th order in the coupling constant $g$. In this way one can in principle obtain expressions for any finite order.

   E.g. Mathematica yields that the phase $\phi$ to order $N=7$ is

   ```
                    2                        4          2
                 2 g       1     8    3   8 g  (-15 + Pi )
     Out[1]= g - ---- + (-(-) + ---) g  + ---------------- + 
                  Pi       3      2                3
                                Pi             3 Pi

                                 6                 2        4
          1   224   20    5   2 g  (10080 - 1120 Pi  + 23 Pi )
    >    (- + --- - ---) g  - -------------------------------- + 
          5     4     2                         5
              Pi    Pi                     15 Pi

            1    8448   1120    1568    7       8
    >    (-(-) + ---- - ---- + ------) g  + O[g]
            7      6      4         2
                 Pi     Pi     45 Pi
   ```
6. After we have determined the phase $\phi$, we can use eq. (5) to find the wave number $k$, and finally eq. (1d) to find the energy $E$.

   E.g. the ground state energy $E_1$ (in energy units of $\frac{\hbar^2}{m L^2}$) to order $N=8$ is$^2$

   ```
               2
             Pi                2    8    2 Pi   3        40    4
     Out[2]= --- + 2 g Pi - 2 g  + (-- - ----) g  + (4 - ---) g  + 
              2                     Pi    3                2
                                                         Pi

          224    80    2 Pi   5      46    1344    560    6
    >    (--- - ---- + ----) g  + (-(--) - ---- + -----) g  + 
            3   3 Pi    5            9       4        2
          Pi                               Pi     3 Pi

          8448   1344    784    2 Pi   7
    >    (---- - ---- + ----- - ----) g  + 
            5      3    15 Pi    7
          Pi     Pi

          88   54912   9856   2464    8       9
    >    (-- - ----- + ---- - -----) g  + O[g]
          15      6      4        2
                Pi     Pi     5 Pi
   ```

---

$^1$For higher-order corrections to RS perturbation theory, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/717102/2451) Phys.SE post.

$^2$To compare with OP's normalization of the $N$th-order energy correction $E_1^{(N)}$, substitute $g\to\frac{1}{\pi}\times$(OP's coupling constant).

Comment: An advantage of Eq. (4) is that it immediately lends itself to a graphical solution. Letting $u=kL/\pi$ (so that $E=E_0 u^2$ where $E_0$ is the $g=0$ ground state), one has $g=-u\cot(\pi u/2)$. The resulting graphical solution for the values of $u$ when $g=1/\pi$ may be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%7B-u+cot%28pi+u%2F2%29%2C1%2Fpi%7D+from+0+to+6).

Comment: Hi @Semiclassical. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you for the clear answer. The only unclear part for me is how you get from Eq. (7) to the results from Mathematica.

Comment: @joerivan: I updated the answer.